# JIRA Python API Report : Sprint Burndown Information

Tags: python, api, rest, jira, python-jira

I am trying to get the Sprint Information for a Burndown chart from  JIRA via its REST API using the python lib found here: jira python documentation

It seems I cannot get the chart itself back via the API so, I’d like to get all information to draw it myself.

Without the Lib I got a view things working:
Although most of my rest-api call (List of Sprints, Sprint Values) work, `rest/greenhopper/1.0/rapid/charts/scopechangeburndownchart` (with would give me the burndown) has access problems.

I really need to use the api though , to proccess the information later on in a differen python class.
`jira.sprint_info(board_id, sprint_id)` or `jira.incompleted_issues(board_id, sprint_id)` work, but my problem is, I don’t get any information about the story points which were estimates for example.

Is there any way to access those story points via the API ? Or can I even get the whole sprint report ? The documentation of the API culdnt help me, so I hope you guise can :)
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out you can acces the estimated Storry Points via

> issue.fields.customfield_10663

and itterate through the wohle sprint to get the sprint goal:

```
# Calculate Incompleted Issues
sum_incompl = 0
for element in jira.incompleted_issues(board_id, sprint_id): #gets Ticket ID
    issue = jira.issue(element.key)
    estimated_storrypoints = issue.fields.customfield_10663  # SP estimated for this ticket
    sum_incompl = sum_incompl + estimated_storrypoints

#Completed
sum_compl = jira.completedIssuesEstimateSum(board_id, sprint_id) 

#Print all
print "Sum Incompleted Issues: ",sum_incompl
print "Sum Completed Issues ", sum_compl
```